# How do I get a new parent ID when cascade creating from a child in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a parent child relationship where the parent doesn't have a reference to the children - something like this :

```
class Child
{
    int Id { get; set;
    Parent Parent { get; set; }
    // + other stuff
}

class Parent
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    // + other stuff
}
```

In the database this just means that the `Child` table has a `ParentID` column. This column can be null - i.e. it's possible to have a `Parent`-less `Child`.

I'm using Fluent conventions to map the domain, but there's an override for this relationship so that we can update a `Child` and create a new `Parent` at the same time :

```
public class ChildOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Child>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Child> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References(x => x.Parent).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

The problem arises when we add a new `Parent` to an existing `Child` and immediately need to read the ID of that Parent (while in a transaction), e.g. :

```
existingChild.CreateParent(parameters);
session.Save(existingChild);
Debug.WriteLine(existingChild.Parent.Id);
```

Which just prints `0` rather than giving me the Id of the new Parent - I had assumed `Cascade.All()` would...well, cascade. Is that wrong?

If I commit the transaction before accessing the Id, everything is fine, or if I save the new Parent explicitly that works too, e.g.

```
// This works
existingChild.CreateParent(parameters);
session.Save(existingChild);
transaction.Commit();
Debug.WriteLine(existingChild.Parent.Id);

// This also works
existingChild.CreateParent(parameters);
session.Save(existingChild);
session.Save(existingChild.Parent);
Debug.WriteLine(existingChild.Parent.Id);
```

Is there any way I can change my override so that saving the child object will allow the parent id to be immediately accessible? (Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good is, that **all is working properly**. And **your mapping is correct**. Because if this snippet is working...

```
// This works
existingChild.CreateParent(parameters);
session.Save(existingChild);
transaction.Commit();
```

... the concept is working as well. Why? What is all about? Why `Commit()` helped to solve that?

Well, because **`ISession`** is an **abstraction**, it is the virtual persistence storage. It **does not** execute any SQL Statements in the moment we call `session.Save()`. It just keeps all information *(gathered during working with that session)* and executing the SQL WRITE Statements only

- if desperately must *(the ID generated by DB is needed for farther stuff)*
- if the session decides *(if allowed ... see below session mode Auto)*
- if explicitly asked for

But better and more precise will be to cite doc:

#### [9.6. Flush](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

> From time to time the ISession will execute the SQL statements needed to synchronize the ADO.NET connection's state with the state of objects held in memory. This process, flush, occurs by default at the following points

...

> Except when you explicity `Flush()`, there **are absolutely no guarantees about when the Session executes the ADO.NET calls**, only the order in which they are executed. **However, NHibernate does guarantee that the ISession.Find(..) methods will never return stale data;** nor will they return the wrong data.
>
> It is possible to change the default behavior so that flush occurs less frequently. The **FlushMode** class defines three different modes: only flush at commit time (and only when the NHibernate ITransaction API is used), flush automatically using the explained routine (will only work inside an explicit NHibernate ITransaction), or never flush unless Flush() is called explicitly. The last mode is useful for long running units of work, where an ISession is kept open and disconnected for a long time (see Section 11.4, “Optimistic concurrency control”).

And there is the answer. The `FlushMode` setting:

```
public enum FlushMode
{
    Unspecified = -1,
    Never = 0,
    Commit = 5,
    Auto = 10,
    Always = 20,
}
```

So, if the FlushMode is `Commit` - only transaction commit triggers the `session.Flush()`

But we can do it any time ourselves:

```
// This works
existingChild.CreateParent(parameters);
session.Save(existingChild);
session.Flush();
```

And now parent will have the ID - becuase session state was just converted into SQL WRITE operations...

Comment: This is useful, thanks. Perhaps I should have been more explicit about the reason for my confusion though - if I use the same process to save a *new* child object, I can get the ID of the child immediately, but not that of the parent. This seems like a bug or at least an inconsistency in NHibernate behaviour.

Comment: Please, do not think about it as inconsistency. It is all by design. We should see session, as a black box.. Do not expect that during the process it has exactly what we would expect. But garanteed is that once FLUSH is called, all the stuff is properly updated in the DB. so, do not solve that, just properly use open - close ...

Comment: It's difficult not to think of it as an inconsistency when it behaves differently for root and leaf objects. I can't actually find anywhere that documents this behaviour either, except to say that nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: @adhocgeek, I am not sure, if I can change your mind here, but I will try once. NHibernate is consistent. Session is an abstraction, which does lot of smart stuff. Lot of smart stuff. And it has its boundaries. So from the moment we open it, until we call Flush - all the changes/dirtiness/states are unpredictable. Some needed to be persisted, some did not. But we should not interact at that moment with Session other way, then finilizing the change - the batch. Once Flush is called, all the stuff is persisted. And that also means: always split READ and WRITE operations in different sessions...

Comment: I've just been looking at the NHibernate source - does it only guarantee to flush the SQL for creating root objects because Save(x) must return an ID? I absolutely understand what you're saying about Session having its boundaries - you have to stop somewhere :D

Answer (score 0):

You are using a ID generation strategy that only generates the ID when the object hits the DB. If you want to have parent ID before that, you'll need to take the ID generation into your hand, using `assigned` strategy.

It's a long topic that I don't want to repeat here. You can read about what you need to do here:
[Don't Let Hibernate Steal Your Identity](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html)

In the article, the ID type is UUID. You can easily implement a custom ID generator for `int` or `long` data types.